# Mapping Date to Instant adds a week

Tags: java, date, java-8

I have the following object of type `java.util.Date` (Java 8):

[image]

So basically 1 January 1235 in CET format.  But the moment I cast this with Instant:

[image]

IntelliJ show me that a whole week has been added! Instant uses UTC format, which explains why one hour is subtracted (one hour difference between CET and UTC). But where does the week come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because most of humanity was using Julian calendar in 1235, and has switched to Gregorian since.

Old style Java Dates do a best effort to account for this when it can deduce for a Locale when it did the switch from Julian to Calendar.

When these switches were made, the date in these countries switched to a different place on the calendar, making it look like the date just skipped a bunch of days.

The newer java.time.* system ignores the historic existence of Julian calendars and is ill-suited to represent time gaps in historic dates.

Comment: Most switches to Gregorian involves "removing" 10 or more days from the Calendar. I was thinking at that direction but since there is only 7 days missing, then I became unsure. It could be the answer. but it could be not as well.

Comment: @KarelG I started looking it up online and I also notice that there's 10 days difference, so I thought that couldn't be it.  But when I use a much more recent date (1 January 1990), then the conversion happens correctly. As in, there is only 1 hour difference.  I'm still confused why it was a 1 week difference.

Comment: @KarelG The switch made it appear that 10 days were ignored. But the idea with switching calendars is that calendars aren't the same.

Comment: There really is not much point to using date-time classes for historical dates, just use text in standard ISO 8601 format, YYYY-MM-DD. It is not like you are calculating overdue invoices for the year 1235.

Comment: I'm very late to my own topic, but I want to add some details. According to wikipedia the Julian calendar gains a day every 134 years compared to the Gregorian calendar. By 1582 the difference has accumulated to 10 days difference, but some countries would adopt the Gregorian calendar at a much later date (centuries) which can span an additional several days difference. A one week difference would then imply my locale (Belgium) was an early adoptar? Belgium has only been declared independent from the Netherlands in 1830 which makes things even more confusing.

Comment: Still, unit tests using more recent years will work fine, so I believe this was the source of the problem.

Comment: @Babyburger it doesn't matter when you locale made the switch to gregorian, it matters that it did make a switch at all. The result of that is that the java.util.Date API shows you what date it was on the Julian calendar with that many milliseconds before Epoch, and the java.time API shows you what date it was on the Gregorian calendar. You then need to compute how many days differences there was between the two back then. Bottom line, all that's happening is that you're using two different calendars.